# How to get `psfragfig` with sibling or super directories on windows?

Tags: errors, windows, psfrag

Assume the following simple latex with some .eps file `testeps.eps` in the: same directory, the parent directory, and a subdirectory called `testsub`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstool}
\begin{document}
    \psfragfig*[width=15cm]{testeps} {}
    \psfragfig*[width=15cm]{testsub/testeps} {}
    \psfragfig*[width=15cm]{../testeps} {}
\end{document}
```

The first two work fine, the last says:

```
"I can't write on file `../testeps-pstool.tex'}
"Emergency stop }
No file "../testeps.tex" or "../testeps-psfrag"
```

I am using miktex on Windows with something like the following for my PdfLaTex (in TeXstudio, but I don't think that matters).

```
pdflatex.exe" -shell-escape -synctex=1 --aux-directory=C:\Windows\Temp  -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

I have tried every permutation of `-shell-escape` and write18 I could find.  Of course, I used to use `\graphicspath` before I converted to psfragfig, but it isn't compatible?

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same issue on Mac os x: like if the compilation fails to write in the super directory! The two first options, mentioned in this post, work properly but not the third one. I need the third option :-(

Answer (score 2):

This feature (not to call it an issue) is pointed out in `pstool-package`-Documentation in CTAN:

> One problem that pstool does not solve on its own is the inclusion of images that do not exist in subdirectories of the main document. For example, `\pstool{../Figures/myfig}` can not process by default because `pdfTEX` usually does not have permission to write into folders that are higher in the heirarchy than the main document. This can be worked around presently in two different ways: (although maybe only for Mac OS X and Linux):

1. Give pdflatex permission to write anywhere with the command: `openout_any=a pdflatex` ...
2. Create a symbolic link in the working directory to a point higher in the path: `ln -s ../testeps ./testeps`, for example, and then refer to the graphics through this symbolic link.

I've successfully tested the second solution.

After spending a whole day looking for a solution, I hope that my first contribution in this group may help others :-)